# PyCharm Unable to save workspace files -.idea permissions

Tags: permissions, workspaces, pycharm

I'm using ubuntu 16.04, and lately i've been getting the following error in PyCharm:

```
PyCharm was unable to save some project files,
are you sure you want to close this project anyway?

Read-only files:
/home/adiel/PycharmProjects/spark-test/.idea/workspace.xml
```

When using `ls -la` on the specified `.idea` folder i get:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 adiel adiel 4096 .idea
```

I've tried using `chmod 777` on the folder, but it remains the same.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108496/pycharm-community-edition-problems-with-read-only-status-on-project-files)

Comment: @Rahul , this is for windows. how do i make this change in ubuntu? thanks

Comment: Did you check the permissions for `workspace.xml` ? Post in your Q also.

Comment: Thanks. when using `sudo chmod` for workspace, problem is solved. if you can post this as an answer i'll mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error message:

```
PyCharm was unable to save some project files,
are you sure you want to close this project anyway?

Read-only files:
/home/adiel/PycharmProjects/spark-test/.idea/workspace.xml
```

According to your error message problme is with `workspace.xml` file. You have to provide appropriate permission to `workspace.xml` file using `sudo  chmod` command.